# How does Resilient Sphere (cast via Contingency) interact with an existing Silence spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I have a situation in my 5E campaign where the party cast a [*silence*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silence) spell to sneak up on a sleeping wizard (super effective).  The wizard was then rudely woken and beaten up to the point where his [*contingency*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contingency) spell of [*resilient sphere*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/resilient-sphere) was triggered.

Does the *resilient sphere* block the effects of the *silence* spell on the wizard now that it exists?  Is he free to cast self-range spells with verbal components and get out of this horrible situation, or is he still silenced unless he can find another way to negate the effect?

Comment: What was _Silence_ cast on? Was it cast on the Wizard, or on the party?

Comment: Welcome Mike! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Excellent first question! Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## It depends on where the point of *silence* was placed

*Silence* requires you to center the spell on a:

> point you choose within range

How *Resilient Sphere* works is dependent upon where that point is.

### If the point is inside the sphere, the wizard is silenced.

The point is within the *resilient sphere* and therefore the sphere wouldn't be able to stop the spell effects because it's already inside. In addition, the *silence* effects would be contained inside the sphere as well and the party would not be affected.

But the wizard isn't stuck in one place, so they are silenced until they move:

> An enclosed creature can use its action to push against the sphere's walls and thus roll the sphere at up to half the creature's speed.

This would allow the wizard inside to move themselves away from the point of silence.

Do note that other creatures can move the globe as well, and may be able to move the point of origin back inside the sphere:

> Similarly, the globe can be picked up and moved by other creatures.

### If the point is outside, the wizard is no longer silenced.

*Resilient Sphere* states:

> Nothing--not physical objects, energy, or other spell effects--can pass through the barrier, in or out, though a creature in the sphere can breathe there.

If the spell effect's point of origin is outside (or the wizard is outside the range of it), the sphere actively prevents spell effects from passing through. The inside of the sphere would be a safe bubble from *silence*.

Comment: Funny to think that spell points-of-origin are able to penetrate anything. You can block the effect, but if the sphere moves onto the origin then the party wouldn't be subject to the spell while the wizard would be.

Comment: @GreySage Ha! Yes! This is a really weird combination of effects.

Comment: If the point of origin is outside the bubble, doesn't that mean magic has to pass through the sphere if it is rolled back onto that point? I don't see how it would take effect a second time, why is the point of origin more special than the rest of the area?